# Is it possible to make a template specialization to be equal to another type

Tags: c++, template-specialization

If I have e.g.:

```
template <class T>
class MyOptional { /*...*/ };
```

I know that I can define a specialization e.g. for `T = bool` which will have a different (separate) implementation:

```
template <> class MyOptional<bool> { /*...*/ };
```

But is it possible to say that this `T=bool` specialization equals to another type (e.g. `MyOptBool`)? 
Something like this:

```
class MyOptBool { /*...*/ };
using Optional<bool> = MyOptBool;  /* impossible but looking for similar functionality */
```

The only think I have found is using inheritance:

```
class MyOptBool { /*...*/ };
template <> class MyOptional<bool> : public MyOptBool {
  using MyOptBool::MyOptBool;
};
```

**1st question:** Is there any more elegant solution? (just for curiosity + I have some conversion issues, etc.).

**2nd question:** Is the "workaround" using inheritance for declaring two classes equal commonly used (in some important libraries, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible approach that allows `Optional<T>` to resolve in this fashion, even though it's not actually ending up specializing `MyOptional`, per se:

```
template<class T>
class MyOptional {};

class MyOptBool {};

template<class T>
struct OptionAlias {

    typedef MyOptional<T> type;
};

template<>
struct OptionAlias<bool> {

    typedef MyOptBool type;
};


template<typename T>
using Optional = typename OptionAlias<T>::type;

void foo()
{
    Optional<int> x;

    Optional<bool> y;
    MyOptBool z=y;
}
```

Comment: Ooh!  Neat.  I've deleted my answer "I don't think you can do much better" - because you obviously can.

Comment: Funny that I'd ramble on about meta-programming to answer the second question, when the answer to the first is just that.

Comment: Oh, yes, it will work. This is actually the opposite I tried to do: I wanted to modify behavior "after" the template is defined, but you place some "adapter" (some kind of "fork") "before" the template definition is instantiated... Thanks! I'll close as answered later not to distract others from another try :)